# What would happen to Superman after a Kryptonite injection?

Tags: dc, superman, kryptonite

If some villian melted kryptonite into a liquid form, and the liquid was then injected into Superman's blood stream, would it permanently limit his powers? Would it eventually kill Superman?

Comment: Molten Kryptonite wouldn't stay molten once in contact with Superman's non-molten-Krytonite temperature blood...

Comment: That makes no sense to me at all, Are you saying that the Krpytonite will solidify when it comes into contact with Superman's blood?  I'm saying that when the Kryptonite enters the blood stream, it will then dissipate into it leave all the little Kryptonite particles inside Superman.

Comment: How does that not make sense? Kryptonite is clearly solid at room temperature. What happens if you melt copper, and try to inject it into your veins? You'd get burned and damaged, but it wouldn't stay molten and flow through your bloodstream, it'd solidify. It's similar to putting melted materials into water, it doesn't say liquid. For reference, "melting" other crystals typically requires temperatures around 1670 degrees Celsius. This is far warmer than his blood, as people around him don't cook.

Comment: You should edit the question and remove the word "melted". Since melted Kryptonite would never actually mingle with Superman's blood. If it were ground into a powder, and mixed with a liquid, it would actually have the ability to mingle with his blood.

Comment: @Gorchestopher Kryptonite can be melted using Acid, according to http://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/arts/comic-books/kryptonite.htm

Comment: @Gorchestopher Melting is the term used to make a Solid into a liquid.  Also, when you mix those two liquids together they won't separate because the heart is pumping blood which is mixing the Kryptonite.

Comment: @Blue Ah, I see where you got that. Acid interaction with Kryptonite would result in water and a Kryptonite salt. "Melting" is the thermodynamic phase transition between the solid and liquid states of matter. I'm a little surprised they'd misuse a term like "melt" in HowStuffWorks. Oh well.

Comment: You learn that in Science Class.... melting point / boiling point

Comment: @Gorchestopher You can't apply acidic reaction attributes here. What if Acid weakens crystal lattice or molecular bonds of Kryptonite.

Comment: @Sachin Shekhar The article is poorly sourced, but I believe a chemical reaction is implied. How would an acid weaken inter-molecular bonds of a substance it is not interacting with at the molecular level? I know Kryptonite is unknown and "special" but acids don't typically cause atomic reactions, and beyond that its interactions are chemical. This situation is limited to what acid can do.

Comment: @Gorchestopher What acid can do (what we know) is limited to tests with terrestrial substances. The situation flow is indeed decided by mystery of Kryptonite.

Comment: @Sachin Shekhar I'll agree to disagree. Acids are called acids if they satisfy chemical criteria. It seems a bit short sighted to say that the only thing that makes it different from other liquids is not the reason it causes the substance in question to react in this unique way. Then again, Superman *does* get his powers from yellow light.

At this point I just want everyone to know that acids don't melt any discovered materials.

Comment: @Gorchestopher Do you know, color and volume attributes of acid aren't chemical attributes. Acids are acids, it doesn't mean they can only posses chemical attributes. Plus, its not known how acids interact with Kryptonite chemically or physically. You've answered yourself in the last sentence: Do you consider Kryptonite as a discovered material in real world (from where you are applying anything around acids)?

Comment: Which type http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryptonite ?

Comment: @Sachin Shekhar Again, I agree to disagree. The color and volume of acid is duplicated by many many non-acid materials. Your implication is that the type of acid that "melts" Kryptonite, does so because the mass, volume, electromagnetic radiation, or ionizing radiation emitted from the acid has some kind of effect on the Kryptonite. That's fine, you can believe that because nothing in cannon bothered to explain what the acid does. If you'll excuse my nonacceptance, I'll continue to believe that what acid does to Kryptonite has something to do with it being acidic.

Comment: People don't need to melt a solid substance with an acid.  There are other ways.  You can melt a substance with heat.  So forget on how to melt the Kryptonite.

Comment: @Blue You can not melt any discovered substances with anything besides heat or pressure. Acid does not melt any terrestrial substances. It's a nomenclature thing. Example: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Would_iron_melt_in_acid

That's what I've been trying to say, but Sachin has been explaining that acid *may* in fact "melt" kryptonite. But please don't be mistaken, acid does not melt anything you can find on this Earth.

Comment: K, but you should explain that the acid will not melt the kyrptonite but disassemble the bonds between atoms.  Assuming kyrptonite isn't an pure element, but a compound.

Comment: @Blue Yes, exactly. Let's use iron as the example so no one is offended. What acid does to iron is remove the iron atoms from the structure to chemically bond them with some other element (whatever the acid is made of). This is true for pure elements and compounds. But yes, you are exactly correct in that the bonds between the atoms are exchanged for different bonds with this other element (whatever the acid has in it besides hydrogen). This chemical reaction is the corrosion we experience with acids.

Comment: @Gorchestopher You are now repeating me in a limited way. Kryptonite can't be considered as discovered substance in your knowledge views of acid. So, you can't say that Kryptonite can't be melted by acid. What if an unknown para-dimensional "Acidic Radiation" weakens crystal lattice or molecular bonds of Kryptonite.. It's better to contact How Stuffs Work for the source.. :) Maybe, source comic would have explained that..

Comment: @SachinShekhar I hadn't considered an extra-dimensional force, because canonically Kryptonite is from the same dimension as us, but I can see how that could be the case. Plausibly, I think that this particular explanation hasn't been considered outside of this thread, and that any use of the word "melt" in that situation has been largely a minor oversight. And once again, so you don't misread me, I agree that your explanation is valid. To beat a dead horse, it *could* be *anything*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *Batman v. Superman*, Kryptonite is introduced into Superman bloodstream via his respiratory system as a gas.

The pathology is as follows:

For the first 30 seconds, *while* breathing the gas, he coughs, gags, seizes up, and spasms, unable to make himself move, and clearly in pain.  However, he remains conscious and can still hear Batman's taunts.

Even before the gas cloud completely disperses, Superman is back on his feet and- apparently- unaware of any compromise to his powers or facilities.  He strikes out at Batman and is *surprised* when Batman blocks his punch.  This differs from his experience of Kryptonite Atmosphere where he expressly says that he feels weak and collapses unconscious... yet otherwise, suffers no further harm from the gas.  Here, it is apparent that continual exposure to Kryptonite could kill... yet how do we account for his continual powers and recovery?

Unlike Kryptonite Atmosphere, Superman clearly still retains a modicum of his powers.  Batman stomps on him wearing a 250 lbs suit with spiked-soled boots from 1.5 stories up.  He kicks him across the floor.  He punches him with metal gauntlets without bruising.  Superman still has durability and throws Batman through a wall and across a room, so he still has strength.  90 seconds after the first phase of exposure, his invulnerability returns as does his power of flight.

What's happening inside?

It's clear that his power-granting organs are under attack, but that his powers are still in effect and in a sense fighting back.

It seems that Kryptonite has a relatively short biological half-life with Kryptonians.  Typically for radiological materials, the biological half-life can only be shorted by elimination and expulsion from the body.  However, it's clear that Kryptonians have a special relationship with radiation.  That makes it possible they have organs meant to manage, filter, and contain bad radiation the way our bodies have livers to break down alcohol or kidneys to clear our blood of toxins.  In the same way ingesting Potassium Iodide can protect your thyroid gland from radiation, Kryptonians may have a similar bodily process for surviving bad radiation.

Therefore, based on dosage, either the Kryptonite overwhelms these processes and powers (like regeneration)... or he makes a gradual recovery.

---

Addendum, towards the end of the New 52, Superman was actually able to metabolize the radiation from Kryptonite as a source of power, albeit to terminal effect.  It's suggested, however, had his issues not been compounded with two additional traumas, he might have recovered.

Answer (score 4):

This raises the interesting question of whether or not Kryponite could be liquified. But to answer this question if somehow Kryptonite was liquified and injected into Superman than he would most likely die. The danger of Krypotonite to Superman is the radiation that comes off of it. So as long as the radiation isn't changed when turned from a solid state into a liquid or even a gas then it would still hurt and could always potentially kill Superman if he receives a long enough or direct enough exposure. I'm pretty sure that a dose of lethal radiation normally kills or permanently harms anyone exposed to it so a radiation that harms Superman would have the same effect on him.

Answer (score 1):

Superman's cells absorb electromagnetic radiation from yellow stars (like Earth's sun) which powers his super powers. Kryptonite's radioactivity interferes with this semi-photosynthetic process, driving the energy out of his cells in a painful fashion.

So, **as long as this radioactivity interference exists, his super powers would be blocked and he would be dead in the end**.

As there's no sufficient canonical documentation of Kryptonite's attributes, it can't be said that it can be melted or not. Also, its not necessary that it'd possess radioactivity in non-crystalline form.

Comment: You stated the radioactivity of the Kryptonite interferes with Superman's cells but then you say that it is not necessary that it possess radioactivity in non-crystalline form. How would he be dead in the last if the Kryptonite is no longer radioactive? Also where did you get that it block his semi-photosynthetic process and drive energy out of his cells?

Comment: @Kevin 1. Check `As long as` in bolded part. The last paragraph says, he might not be dead based on unclear attributes of Kryptonite. 2. That part is popular one. You can find it in many comics. A part is explained by Lex Luthor in Superman - The Movie too. I have added that to Wikipedia too which is supported by community with solid sources. Check them.

Comment: Please check the sentence you wrote *And, its also not necessary that it'd possess radioactivity in non-crystaline form.* this is what I wanted clarified. Also I'm not arguing with you, your answer is the same as the one I gave. I was just asking for clarification on what you meant. I don't find the wiki entry useful on Kryptonite as most of the sources given aren't linkable and pretty much anyone can change wiki so it can be wrong but I did find this http://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/arts/comic-books/kryptonite.htm which has good sources and explains the process better.

Comment: @Kevin Your link is nice, but it doesn't tell that radioactivity would be intact or not. But, it tells without source that Kryptonite can be melted using Acid.

Comment: I gave Sachin the answer because he stated put what would happen and followed with the functionality of Kryptonite interference with the Superman's cellular functions.

Comment: I'm going to complain to "How Stuff Works" about their misuse of the word "melt". Atrocious.

Comment: @Blue I just want to clarify I am not challenging Sachin Shekhar's answer or even saying mine was better. I honestly was curious about the information he gave and also honestly confused by what he wrote. That's all. As the asker of a question you do not need to explain why you choose one answer over another but it does help to know.

Comment: Yea but your post seemed like you were complaining a bit

Comment: This is highly debatable on multiple levels considering how many different forms Kryptonite has.

Answer (score 0):

It depends also on if the "needle" could be able to penetrate Supermans skin to be able to seep the kryptonite into his blood because the needle might just snap in half or something and not even go through his skin.

Comment: The question is assuming the needle can penetrate his skin. While frame challenges are ok, you should still attempt to address the original question (Whether or not it would kill him?).